# Do Benzyl Halides undergo SN1 or SN2 with Ammonia?

Tags: aromatic-compounds, nucleophilic-substitution

[image: Benzyl Chloride + Ammonia yields Benzylamine]

Does this reaction show SN1 or SN2 mechanism? Our teacher told that it shows SN2. But wouldn't the stability of benzylic carbocation mean an inclination towards SN1?

Comment: It also increases the rate of SN2 substitution.

Comment: Why/How would it do so? @Zhe

Comment: Consult a textbook for more details, but neighboring group effects are known to affect SN2 rates, presumably due to the adjacent orbitals contributing to a more stabilized transition state.

Answer (score 2):

### Answer to Your Question$^\text{1}$

$\text{S}_\text{N}\text{1}$ and $\text{S}_\text{N}\text{2}$ reactivities between benzyl chloride and ammonia are solvent and substituent dependent.

[image: illustration of effects of solvent and substituent on the reaction between benzyl chloride and ammonia to form benzylamine]

#### Effects of Solvent

In liquid ammonia, there is strong evidence that it will follow an $\text{S}_\text{N}\text{2}$ mechanism, while in aqueous/binary medium, it is likely to show mixed $\text{S}_\text{N}\text{1}$ and $\text{S}_\text{N}\text{2}$ mechanism.

> The rate of solvolysis in liquid ammonia is retarded dramatically when one of methylene hydrogen of benzyl chloride in the α-position is replaced by a methyl group, α-methyl benzyl chloride is solvolyzed about 130 times slower than benzyl chloride. This is strong evidence for solvolysis occurring by an $\text{S}_\text{N}\text{2}$ mechanism due to a more sterically hindered transition state.

#### Effects of Substituent

In liquid ammonia, substituents on the benzene ring only feebly affect the kinetics and reaction mechanism while strongly affecting both in case of aqueous/binary medium.

> There is no clear consensus on the mechanism of hydrolysis of benzyl halides in water and aqueous binary solvents, although that for 4-methoxybenzyl halides is described as an $\text{S}_\text{N}\text{1}$ mechanism with the intermediate formation of a carbocation, and that for the 4-nitro derivative is claimed to be $\text{S}_\text{N}\text{2}$.

This reasons that reaction between unsubstituted benzyl chloride and ammonia (in aqueous/binary medium) might follow a mixed $\text{S}_\text{N}\text{1}$ and $\text{S}_\text{N}\text{2}$ reaction mechanism.

### [Applications of Benzylamine](https://products.basf.com/global/en/ci/benzylamine.html)

Reaction between benzyl chloride and ammonia is of paramount importance, being one the major synthesis routes to the production of benzylamine, which is used within the coatings industry, for example, as a building block for additives and solvents, and it is a valuable intermediate for various applications and a building block for chemical synthesis like for the production of Active Pharma Ingredients (APIs) and crop protection agents.

I am surprised that a reaction, with industrial applications, has not been studied much. It would definitely be an interesting topic of research.

### Reference

1. Pi, J. (2011), Kinetics and Mechanisms of Organic Reactions in Liquid Ammonia. Doctoral thesis, University of Huddersfield. Available as [PDF](https://eprints.hud.ac.uk/id/eprint/10033/).